# Struggling with indexes in array php

Tags: php

Fetching json data from rapidapi and trying to put it into a canvasjs chart. I belive the problem why my chart doesnt print is because the array that i create doesn't have the right indexes. My array has the index 0 on each element which the desired has not, it has indexes 0-13.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</style>
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: 7b91a7c6f1mshc7c602f9ec25f2ap180924jsna8c9958d399f"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $array = json_decode($response,true);
  $result = $array['response'];
      echo "<table class='styled-chart' id=''>";
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
          $countryArray = array($value['country']);
          $deathArray = array($value['deaths']);
          $caseArray = array($value['cases']);
            foreach ($countryArray as $key => $value) {
              $countries = $value;
              echo "<th>Countries</th><td>".$countries."</td>";
            }
              foreach ($caseArray as $key => $value) {
              $cases = $value['total'];
              echo "<th>Cases</th><td>".$cases."</td>";
                            $mergedCases['x'] = $value['total'];
            }
            foreach ($deathArray as $key => $value) {
              $deaths = $value['total'];
              echo "<th>Deaths</th><td>".$deaths."</td>";
                            $mergedDeaths['z'] = $value['total'];
            }
$dataPoints = array($mergedDeaths + $mergedCases);
print_r($dataPoints);
          }
        echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
    }
        /*
        correct array
$dataPoints = array(
                                    array("x"=> 10, "y"=> 41),
                                    array("x"=> 20, "y"=> 35, "indexLabel"=> "Lowest"),
                                    array("x"=> 30, "y"=> 50),
                                    array("x"=> 40, "y"=> 45),
                                    array("x"=> 50, "y"=> 52),
                                    array("x"=> 60, "y"=> 68),
                                    array("x"=> 70, "y"=> 38),
                                    array("x"=> 80, "y"=> 71, "indexLabel"=> "Highest"),
                                    array("x"=> 90, "y"=> 52),
                                    array("x"=> 100, "y"=> 60),
                                    array("x"=> 110, "y"=> 36),
                                    array("x"=> 120, "y"=> 49),
                                    array("x"=> 130, "y"=> 41)
                                );
print_r($dataPoints);*/



?>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    theme: "light1", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
    title:{
        text: "Simple Column Chart with Index Labels"
    },
    axisY:{
        includeZero: true
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
        //indexLabel: "{y}", //Shows y value on all Data Points
        indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
        indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
        dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$mergedDeaths returns array: 
Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => 4641 ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => 2 ) Array ( [z] => 1 ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => 2 ) Array ( [z] => 273 ) Array ( [z] => 212 ) Array ( [z] => 789 ) Array ( [z] => 87 ) Array ( [z] => 1350 ) Array ( [z] => 367 ) Array ( [z] => 26 ) Array ( [z] => 114 ) Array ( [z] => 189 ) Array ( [z] => 219 ) Array ( [z] => 835 ) Array ( [z] => 131 ) Array ( [z] => 139 ) Array ( [z] => 63 ) Array ( [z] => 54 ) Array ( [z] => 63 ) Array ( [z] => 86 ) Array ( [z] => 34 ) Array ( [z] => 11 ) Array ( [z] => 135 ) Array ( [z] => 294 ) Array ( [z] => 106 ) Array ( [z] => 7 ) Array ( [z] => 62 ) Array ( [z] => 73 ) Array ( [z] => 36 ) Array ( [z] => 9 ) Array ( [z] => 7 ) Array ( [z] => 43 ) Array ( [z] => 729 ) Array ( [z] => 308 ) Array ( [z] => 153 ) Array ( [z] => 28 ) Array ( [z] => 183 ) Array ( [z] => 160 ) Array ( [z] => 854 ) Array ( [z] => 1 ) Array ( [z] => 103 ) Array ( [z] => 38 ) Array ( [z] => 13 ) Array ( [z] => 170 ) Array ( [z] => 440 ) Array ( [z] => 697 ) Array ( [z] => 385 ) Array ( [z] => 113 ) Array ( [z] => 985 ) Array ( [z] => 365 ) Array ( [z] => 21 ) Array ( [z] => 84 ) Array ( [z] => 130 ) Array ( [z] => 382 ) Array ( [z] => 124 ) Array ( [z] => 163 ) Array ( [z] => 13 ) Array ( [z] => 225 ) Array ( [z] => 6 ) Array ( [z] => 2148 ) Array ( [z] => 138 ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => 803 ) Array ( [z] => 101 ) Array ( [z] => 125 ) Array ( [z] => 6 ) Array ( [z] => 12 ) Array ( [z] => 192 ) Array ( [z] => 164 ) Array ( [z] => 271 ) Array ( [z] => 187 ) Array ( [z] => 4929 ) Array ( [z] => 9261 ) Array ( [z] => 2709 ) Array ( [z] => 7509 ) Array ( [z] => 1445 ) Array ( [z] => 1927 ) Array ( [z] => 1900 ) Array ( [z] => 5701 ) Array ( [z] => 2177 ) Array ( [z] => 2991 ) Array ( [z] => 3055 ) Array ( [z] => 1637 ) Array ( [z] => 722 ) Array ( [z] => 24522 ) Array ( [z] => 8622 ) Array ( [z] => 7679 ) Array ( [z] => 218 ) Array ( [z] => 18 ) Array ( [z] => 2522 ) Array ( [z] => 1391 ) Array ( [z] => 3596 ) Array ( [z] => 649 ) Array ( [z] => 3150 ) Array ( [z] => 677 ) Array ( [z] => 677 ) Array ( [z] => 854 ) Array ( [z] => 4257 ) Array ( [z] => 862 ) Array ( [z] => 19434 ) Array ( [z] => 3143 ) Array ( [z] => 797 ) Array ( [z] => 5352 ) Array ( [z] => 4375 ) Array ( [z] => 1474 ) Array ( [z] => 11481 ) Array ( [z] => 6429 ) Array ( [z] => 1337 ) Array ( [z] => 993 ) Array ( [z] => 10888 ) Array ( [z] => 15749 ) Array ( [z] => 731 ) Array ( [z] => 5649 ) Array ( [z] => 3973 ) Array ( [z] => 2688 ) Array ( [z] => 3496 ) Array ( [z] => 6874 ) Array ( [z] => 5463 ) Array ( [z] => 1054 ) Array ( [z] => 2200 ) Array ( [z] => 110 ) Array ( [z] => 298 ) Array ( [z] => 4125 ) Array ( [z] => 4022 ) Array ( [z] => 918 ) Array ( [z] => 3800 ) Array ( [z] => 1458 ) Array ( [z] => 2929 ) Array ( [z] => 1965 ) Array ( [z] => 2631 ) Array ( [z] => 394 ) Array ( [z] => 1325 ) Array ( [z] => 648 ) Array ( [z] => 165 ) Array ( [z] => 1395 ) Array ( [z] => 383 ) Array ( [z] => 1228 ) Array ( [z] => 312 ) Array ( [z] => 982 ) Array ( [z] => 672 ) Array ( [z] => 401 ) Array ( [z] => 303 ) Array ( [z] => 3517 ) Array ( [z] => 564 ) Array ( [z] => 21903 ) Array ( [z] => 8179 ) Array ( [z] => 9023 ) Array ( [z] => 5715 ) Array ( [z] => 11951 ) Array ( [z] => 2302 ) Array ( [z] => 9159 ) Array ( [z] => 1316 ) Array ( [z] => 15742 ) Array ( [z] => 6560 ) Array ( [z] => 9069 ) Array ( [z] => 9706 ) Array ( [z] => 8521 ) Array ( [z] => 16496 ) Array ( [z] => 16063 ) Array ( [z] => 36784 ) Array ( [z] => 10360 ) Array ( [z] => 28509 ) Array ( [z] => 7197 ) Array ( [z] => 35513 ) Array ( [z] => 8357 ) Array ( [z] => 17430 ) Array ( [z] => 18734 ) Array ( [z] => 2555 ) Array ( [z] => 6901 ) Array ( [z] => 103266 ) Array ( [z] => 144157 ) Array ( [z] => 171396 ) Array ( [z] => 21224 ) Array ( [z] => 22156 ) Array ( [z] => 323944 ) Array ( [z] => 27009 ) Array ( [z] => 31165 ) Array ( [z] => 13793 ) Array ( [z] => 57263 ) Array ( [z] => 5997 ) Array ( [z] => 18572 ) Array ( [z] => 29023 ) Array ( [z] => 30364 ) Array ( [z] => 212630 ) Array ( [z] => 521965 ) Array ( [z] => 13660 ) Array ( [z] => 6787 ) Array ( [z] => 10630 ) Array ( [z] => 39990 ) Array ( [z] => 16793 ) Array ( [z] => 16431 ) Array ( [z] => 19759 ) Array ( [z] => 373713 ) Array ( [z] => 115838 ) Array ( [z] => 65340 ) Array ( [z] => 140854 ) Array ( [z] => 155903 ) Array ( [z] => 6932 ) Array ( [z] => 662011 ) Array ( [z] => 253389 ) Array ( [z] => 98568 ) Array ( [z] => 42944 ) Array ( [z] => 128344 ) Array ( [z] => 139749 ) Array ( [z] => 29126 ) Array ( [z] => 108220 ) Array ( [z] => 35421 ) Array ( [z] => 59976 ) Array ( [z] => 100147 ) Array ( [z] => 25198 ) Array ( [z] => 38311 ) Array ( [z] => 15933 ) Array ( [z] => 45865 ) Array ( [z] => 133435 ) Array ( [z] => 14048 ) Array ( [z] => 21993 ) Array ( [z] => 2783 ) Array ( [z] => 161766 ) Array ( [z] => 28652 ) Array ( [z] => 6223802 ) Array ( [z] => 1015451 ) Array ( [z] => 1291992 ) Array ( [z] => 10017 ) Array ( [z] => 1416271 ) Array ( [z] => 1799239 ) Array ( [z] => 1452879 ) Array ( [z] => 2 ) Array ( [z] => 11 ) Array ( [z] => ) Array ( [z] => 2 ) Array ( [z] => 1 )
```

```
}
foreach ($caseArray as $key => $value) {
echo "<th>Cases</th><td>".$cases."</td>";
$mergedCases['x'] = $value['total'];
}
$mergedCases returns array: 
Array ( [x] => 3 ) Array ( [x] => 6162 ) Array ( [x] => 5948 ) Array ( [x] => 1 ) Array ( [x] => 5936 ) Array ( [x] => 2731 ) Array ( [x] => 454 ) Array ( [x] => 5559 ) Array ( [x] => 2 ) Array ( [x] => 185035 ) Array ( [x] => 2537 ) Array ( [x] => 3075 ) Array ( [x] => 29 ) Array ( [x] => 128 ) Array ( [x] => 712 ) Array ( [x] => 9 ) Array ( [x] => 4432 ) Array ( [x] => 10 ) Array ( [x] => 3941 ) Array ( [x] => 14 ) Array ( [x] => 7 ) Array ( [x] => 82 ) Array ( [x] => 4190 ) Array ( [x] => 5947 ) Array ( [x] => 176 ) Array ( [x] => 36963 ) Array ( [x] => 34345 ) Array ( [x] => 33391 ) Array ( [x] => 28416 ) Array ( [x] => 26471 ) Array ( [x] => 23094 ) Array ( [x] => 21406 ) Array ( [x] => 15683 ) Array ( [x] => 15598 ) Array ( [x] => 14165 ) Array ( [x] => 30594 ) Array ( [x] => 12901 ) Array ( [x] => 12437 ) Array ( [x] => 11988 ) Array ( [x] => 11406 ) Array ( [x] => 10279 ) Array ( [x] => 9920 ) Array ( [x] => 9349 ) Array ( [x] => 62057 ) Array ( [x] => 9025 ) Array ( [x] => 7539 ) Array ( [x] => 7402 ) Array ( [x] => 6751 ) Array ( [x] => 6332 ) Array ( [x] => 30658 ) Array ( [x] => 8877 ) Array ( [x] => 119780 ) Array ( [x] => 99194 ) Array ( [x] => 40709 ) Array ( [x] => 34658 ) Array ( [x] => 15906 ) Array ( [x] => 8100 ) Array ( [x] => 35983 ) Array ( [x] => 9733 ) Array ( [x] => 53104 ) Array ( [x] => 64121 ) Array ( [x] => 43660 ) Array ( [x] => 55773 ) Array ( [x] => 89028 ) Array ( [x] => 38722 ) Array ( [x] => 8178 ) Array ( [x] => 36459 ) Array ( [x] => 32910 ) Array ( [x] => 24079 ) Array ( [x] => 14649 ) Array ( [x] => 64513 ) Array ( [x] => 37391 ) Array ( [x] => 11994 ) Array ( [x] => 11971 ) Array ( [x] => 17003 ) Array ( [x] => 22853 ) Array ( [x] => 20853 ) Array ( [x] => 17388 ) Array ( [x] => 26952 ) Array ( [x] => 18491 ) Array ( [x] => 81857 ) Array ( [x] => 11817 ) Array ( [x] => 17369 ) Array ( [x] => 33851 ) Array ( [x] => 87023 ) Array ( [x] => 17494 ) Array ( [x] => 7681 ) Array ( [x] => 129238 ) Array ( [x] => 85968 ) Array ( [x] => 85728 ) Array ( [x] => 80035 ) Array ( [x] => 79276 ) Array ( [x] => 72596 ) Array ( [x] => 72328 ) Array ( [x] => 70102 ) Array ( [x] => 64348 ) Array ( [x] => 63368 ) Array ( [x] => 60385 ) Array ( [x] => 58681 ) Array ( [x] => 57331 ) Array ( [x] => 55990 ) Array ( [x] => 7378 ) Array ( [x] => 47594 ) Array ( [x] => 41660 ) Array ( [x] => 41652 ) Array ( [x] => 37038 ) Array ( [x] => 949583 ) Array ( [x] => 470273 ) Array ( [x] => 161101 ) Array ( [x] => 2495996 ) Array ( [x] => 831149 ) Array ( [x] => 522042 ) Array ( [x] => 903908 ) Array ( [x] => 768794 ) Array ( [x] => 1527326 ) Array ( [x] => 469365 ) Array ( [x] => 1305396 ) Array ( [x] => 200980 ) Array ( [x] => 136076 ) Array ( [x] => 238313 ) Array ( [x] => 200502 ) Array ( [x] => 1653118 ) Array ( [x] => 511977 ) Array ( [x] => 1049797 ) Array ( [x] => 1765258 ) Array ( [x] => 422770 ) Array ( [x] => 178457 ) Array ( [x] => 140182 ) Array ( [x] => 813243 ) Array ( [x] => 567644 ) Array ( [x] => 2882590 ) Array ( [x] => 978674 ) Array ( [x] => 164051 ) Array ( [x] => 1498834 ) Array ( [x] => 895663 ) Array ( [x] => 363654 ) Array ( [x] => 1198438 ) Array ( [x] => 1160300 ) Array ( [x] => 140130 ) Array ( [x] => 1113547 ) Array ( [x] => 388891 ) Array ( [x] => 997766 ) Array ( [x] => 1952362 ) Array ( [x] => 752705 ) Array ( [x] => 2323284 ) Array ( [x] => 1996868 ) Array ( [x] => 792365 ) Array ( [x] => 1879480 ) Array ( [x] => 1694216 ) Array ( [x] => 1100073 ) Array ( [x] => 662912 ) Array ( [x] => 1419729 ) Array ( [x] => 612602 ) Array ( [x] => 1149447 ) Array ( [x] => 255648 ) Array ( [x] => 1095613 ) Array ( [x] => 1038668 ) Array ( [x] => 895775 ) Array ( [x] => 865585 ) Array ( [x] => 1164411 ) Array ( [x] => 844892 ) Array ( [x] => 308620 ) Array ( [x] => 837558 ) Array ( [x] => 265741 ) Array ( [x] => 234251 ) Array ( [x] => 648446 ) Array ( [x] => 630888 ) Array ( [x] => 581678 ) Array ( [x] => 578733 ) Array ( [x] => 563183 ) Array ( [x] => 516431 ) Array ( [x] => 501862 ) Array ( [x] => 464366 ) Array ( [x] => 421268 ) Array ( [x] => 376437 ) Array ( [x] => 360445 ) Array ( [x] => 323614 ) Array ( [x] => 318515 ) Array ( [x] => 305859 ) Array ( [x] => 274504 ) Array ( [x] => 247278 ) Array ( [x] => 229311 ) Array ( [x] => 225329 ) Array ( [x] => 183974 ) Array ( [x] => 178313 ) Array ( [x] => 162089 ) Array ( [x] => 158074 ) Array ( [x] => 147519 ) Array ( [x] => 142222 ) Array ( [x] => 129758 ) Array ( [x] => 974478 ) Array ( [x] => 11662214 ) Array ( [x] => 27771024 ) Array ( [x] => 21747638 ) Array ( [x] => 16353495 ) Array ( [x] => 8015576 ) Array ( [x] => 5727668 ) Array ( [x] => 4046953 ) Array ( [x] => 3972963 ) Array ( [x] => 3551790 ) Array ( [x] => 3530258 ) Array ( [x] => 2949407 ) Array ( [x] => 7374251 ) Array ( [x] => 56547763 ) Array ( [x] => 3555739 ) Array ( [x] => 43044280 ) Array ( [x] => 5419380 ) Array ( [x] => 4031761 ) Array ( [x] => 3882395 ) Array ( [x] => 4059444 ) Array ( [x] => 18084151 ) Array ( [x] => 5985517 ) Array ( [x] => 7208968 ) Array ( [x] => 6040432 ) Array ( [x] => 30252618 ) Array ( [x] => 6537109 ) Array ( [x] => 14994937 ) Array ( [x] => 10432547 ) Array ( [x] => 9060923 ) Array ( [x] => 6089662 ) Array ( [x] => 4990465 ) Array ( [x] => 4389025 ) Array ( [x] => 3683211 ) Array ( [x] => 3741230 ) Array ( [x] => 3632318 ) Array ( [x] => 23454640 ) Array ( [x] => 3719485 ) Array ( [x] => 145744487 ) Array ( [x] => 15730676 ) Array ( [x] => 3242037 ) Array ( [x] => 97396590 ) Array ( [x] => 82317040 ) Array ( [x] => 186823964 ) Array ( [x] => 11824761 ) Array ( [x] => 504875395 ) Array ( [x] => 9 ) Array ( [x] => 712 ) Array ( [x] => 17 ) Array ( [x] => 39 ) Array ( [x] => 32 )
```

Desired array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [x] => 10 [y] => 41 ) [1] => Array ( [x] => 20 [y] => 35 [indexLabel] => Lowest ) [2] => Array ( [x] => 30 [y] => 50 ) [3] => Array ( [x] => 40 [y] => 45 ) [4] => Array ( [x] => 50 [y] => 52 ) [5] => Array ( [x] => 60 [y] => 68 ) [6] => Array ( [x] => 70 [y] => 38 ) [7] => Array ( [x] => 80 [y] => 71 [indexLabel] => Highest ) [8] => Array ( [x] => 90 [y] => 52 ) [9] => Array ( [x] => 100 [y] => 60 ) [10] => Array ( [x] => 110 [y] => 36 ) [11] => Array ( [x] => 120 [y] => 49 ) [12] => Array ( [x] => 130 [y] => 41 ) )
```

Otherwise canvasjs won't accept the input into the chart.
My out put:

```
$dataPoints = array($mergedDeaths + $mergedCases);
print_r($dataPoints);
Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 219 [x] => 14165 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 131 [x] => 12901 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 139 [x] => 12437 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 63 [x] => 11988 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 54 [x] => 11406 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 63 [x] => 10279 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 86 [x] => 9920 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 34 [x] => 9349 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 11 [x] => 9025 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 135 [x] => 7539 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 294 [x] => 7402 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 106 [x] => 6751 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 7 [x] => 6332 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 3 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 62 [x] => 6162 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 73 [x] => 5948 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 36 [x] => 5936 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 9 [x] => 2731 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 7 [x] => 454 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 43 [x] => 5559 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 2 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 308 [x] => 8877 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 4641 [x] => 185035 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 160 [x] => 8100 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1 [x] => 2537 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 103 [x] => 9733 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 13 [x] => 3075 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 170 [x] => 8178 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 113 [x] => 14649 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 365 [x] => 11994 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 21 [x] => 11971 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 29 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 128 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 13 [x] => 712 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2 [x] => 9 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6 [x] => 4432 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1 [x] => 10 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2148 [x] => 11817 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 3941 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 14 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 7 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 82 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 125 [x] => 7681 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6 [x] => 4190 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 12 [x] => 5947 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2 [x] => 176 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 192 [x] => 7378 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 273 [x] => 36963 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 212 [x] => 34345 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 789 [x] => 33391 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 87 [x] => 28416 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1350 [x] => 26471 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 367 [x] => 23094 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 26 [x] => 21406 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 114 [x] => 15683 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 189 [x] => 15598 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 835 [x] => 30594 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 4929 [x] => 62057 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1445 [x] => 161101 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 729 [x] => 30658 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1927 [x] => 119780 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1900 [x] => 99194 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 153 [x] => 40709 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 28 [x] => 34658 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 183 [x] => 15906 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 3055 [x] => 136076 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 854 [x] => 35983 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 7679 [x] => 178457 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 218 [x] => 140182 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 18 [x] => 53104 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1391 [x] => 64121 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 3596 [x] => 164051 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 649 [x] => 43660 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 3150 [x] => 55773 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 677 [x] => 89028 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 38 [x] => 38722 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 440 [x] => 36459 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 697 [x] => 32910 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 385 [x] => 24079 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 854 [x] => 140130 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 862 [x] => 64513 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 985 [x] => 37391 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 84 [x] => 17003 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 130 [x] => 22853 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 382 [x] => 20853 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 124 [x] => 17388 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 163 [x] => 26952 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 225 [x] => 18491 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 797 [x] => 81857 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 138 [x] => 17369 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 803 [x] => 33851 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1337 [x] => 87023 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 101 [x] => 17494 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 298 [x] => 178313 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 4125 [x] => 162089 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 4022 [x] => 158074 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 918 [x] => 147519 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 3800 [x] => 142222 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1458 [x] => 129758 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2929 [x] => 129238 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1965 [x] => 85968 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2631 [x] => 85728 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 394 [x] => 80035 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1325 [x] => 79276 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 648 [x] => 72596 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 165 [x] => 72328 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1395 [x] => 70102 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 383 [x] => 64348 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1228 [x] => 63368 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 312 [x] => 60385 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 982 [x] => 58681 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 672 [x] => 57331 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 401 [x] => 55990 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 303 [x] => 47594 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 164 [x] => 41660 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 271 [x] => 41652 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 187 [x] => 37038 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 7509 [x] => 470273 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 564 [x] => 831149 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 5701 [x] => 522042 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 8179 [x] => 768794 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2177 [x] => 469365 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2991 [x] => 200980 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1637 [x] => 238313 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 722 [x] => 200502 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 24522 [x] => 511977 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 8622 [x] => 422770 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 5715 [x] => 813243 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2522 [x] => 567644 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 677 [x] => 363654 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 4257 [x] => 388891 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 9069 [x] => 752705 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 9706 [x] => 792365 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 16496 [x] => 662912 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 19434 [x] => 612602 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 3143 [x] => 255648 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 9262 [x] => 308620 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6874 [x] => 265741 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2709 [x] => 234251 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 18734 [x] => 648446 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2555 [x] => 630888 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 5352 [x] => 581678 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 4375 [x] => 578733 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1474 [x] => 563183 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 11481 [x] => 516431 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6429 [x] => 501862 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 993 [x] => 464366 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 10888 [x] => 421268 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 15749 [x] => 376437 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 731 [x] => 360445 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 5649 [x] => 323614 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 3973 [x] => 318515 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2688 [x] => 305859 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 3496 [x] => 274504 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 5463 [x] => 247278 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1054 [x] => 229311 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2200 [x] => 225329 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 110 [x] => 183974 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 3517 [x] => 949583 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 103266 [x] => 11662214 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 144157 [x] => 27771024 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 171396 [x] => 21747638 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 21224 [x] => 16353495 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 22156 [x] => 8015576 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 323944 [x] => 5727668 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 27009 [x] => 4046953 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 31165 [x] => 3972963 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 13793 [x] => 3551790 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 57263 [x] => 3530258 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 5997 [x] => 2949407 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 18572 [x] => 2495996 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 29023 [x] => 7374251 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 21903 [x] => 903908 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 30364 [x] => 1527326 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1291992 [x] => 56547763 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 212630 [x] => 3555739 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 521965 [x] => 43044280 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 13660 [x] => 1305396 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6787 [x] => 5419380 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 10630 [x] => 4031761 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 39990 [x] => 3882395 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 16793 [x] => 1653118 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 9023 [x] => 1049797 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 16431 [x] => 4059444 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 19759 [x] => 1765258 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 373713 [x] => 18084151 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 115838 [x] => 5985517 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 65340 [x] => 2882590 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 11951 [x] => 978674 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 140854 [x] => 7208968 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 155903 [x] => 6040432 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6932 [x] => 1498834 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2302 [x] => 895663 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 9159 [x] => 1198438 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1316 [x] => 1160300 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 662011 [x] => 30252618 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 10017 [x] => 6537109 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 15742 [x] => 1113547 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 98568 [x] => 14994937 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 42944 [x] => 10432547 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 128344 [x] => 9060923 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6560 [x] => 997766 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 139749 [x] => 6089662 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 29126 [x] => 1952362 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 108220 [x] => 4990465 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 35421 [x] => 4389025 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 59976 [x] => 3683211 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 100147 [x] => 3741230 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 25198 [x] => 2323284 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 38311 [x] => 3632318 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 15933 [x] => 1996868 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 45865 [x] => 1879480 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 133435 [x] => 23454640 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 14048 [x] => 1694216 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 8521 [x] => 1100073 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 21993 [x] => 3719485 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2783 [x] => 1419729 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1416271 [x] => 145744487 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 161766 [x] => 15730676 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 36784 [x] => 1149447 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 10360 [x] => 1095613 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 28652 [x] => 3242037 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1452879 [x] => 97396590 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 28509 [x] => 1038668 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1015451 [x] => 82317040 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1799240 [x] => 186823964 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 7197 [x] => 895775 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 253390 [x] => 11824761 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6223804 [x] => 504875395 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 35513 [x] => 865585 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 16064 [x] => 1164411 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 8357 [x] => 844892 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 17430 [x] => 837558 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 6901 [x] => 974478 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2 [x] => 9 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 11 [x] => 712 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => [x] => 17 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 2 [x] => 39 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 1 [x] => 32 ) )
```

Comment: You keep overwriting the same element each time through the `foreach` loop. You're not creating an array of all the values.

Comment: Where do `y` and `indexLabel` come from?

Comment: @barman sorry didnt see the errors in my post ive edited them, the index label doesnt really matter i think, but the index of the array does i think

Comment: I still don't understand. Your code creates `x` and `z`, but your desired array has `x` and `y`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you want  something like `$deaths = array_column($deathArray, 'total');`

Comment: @barmar Yeah sorry still editing the post, kinda new to this, the problem is the index in my array: Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 219 [x] => 14165 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 131 [x] => 12901 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 139 [x] => 12437 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 63 [x] => 11988 ) ). You see it return the index 0 for each element, in my desired result you can see the index goes from 0-13.

Comment: A bit difficult to make sense of what all you have going on and what you're actually wanting. In essence it appears that you are not using the key of the iterated array to retain placement of the new array index, `$mergedCases[$key]['x'] = $value['total']` and `$mergedDeaths[$key]['z'] = $value['total']`

Comment: @willb. It's not the index of the z and x that's the issue, it's the 0 in: Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 131 [x] => 12901 ).

Comment: It is because, `$a['x'] = 1` will always output `array( 'x' => 1 )`, since you're overwriting the index of `x` on each iteration of the `foreach`. Unless you have something else going on in your code that is moving the index that we cannot see from your example, if so please update your question to provide the full context

Comment: @willb. Yeah you're right ill edit the post again.

Comment: Okay posted the full code, also it's live on: https://poggers.online/test/test, where you can see the chart is empty because it's not receiving data, if i uncomment the premade array it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the value of the `$mergedCases` and `$mergedDeaths` arrays are being overwritten on each iteration, causing the resulting `$dataPoints` to be invalid. To resolve the issue, the index of the array needs to be incremented.

The debugging call of `print_r($dataPoints);` inside the iteration of the `$array['response']` data, was showing you the individual array value as opposed to the desired final array result to be passed to canvas.js.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 219 [x] => 14165 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [z] => 131 [x] => 12901 ) )
```

As opposed to the desired:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [z] => 219 [x] => 14165 )
    [1] => Array ( [z] => 131 [x] => 12901 )
)
```

Additionally, you are also overwriting `foreach ($result as $key => $value)` in your nested `foreach` loops, to resolve the issue use different variable names for them such as `foreach($deathArray as $k => $v)`.
However, creating an array of the individual properties in `$countryArray = array($value['country']);`, `$deathArray = array($value['deaths']);` `$caseArray = array($value['cases']);` is redundant, since they do not need to be iterated over.

As you are not utilizing the individual `$mergedCases` or `$mergedDeaths` arrays, refactor your approach to append to the `$dataPoints` array using the parent index `$key` instead to maintain the array placement.

**Example**

```
$array = json_decode($response, true);
$result = $array['response'];
$dataPoints = [];
$phH = $phL = $highest = $lowest = null;
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $dataPoints[$key] = [
       'x' => $cases = $value['cases']['total'],
       'y' => $deaths = $value['deaths']['total'],
    ];
    if (null === $phH || $highest < $deaths) {
        // determine highest point
        $highest = $deaths ? : 0;
        $phH = $key;
    }
    if (null === $phL || $lowest > $deaths) {
        // determine lowest point
        $lowest = $deaths ? : 0;
        $phL = $key;
    }
}

// assign highest and lowest points
$dataPoints[$phL]['indexLabel'] = 'Lowest';
$dataPoints[$phH]['indexLabel'] = 'Highest';

var_export($dataPoints);
```

**Result**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'x' => 7539,
    'y' => 135,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'x' => 7402,
    'y' => 294,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'x' => 6751,
    'y' => 106,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'x' => 6332,
    'y' => 7,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'x' => 3,
    'y' => NULL,
    'indexLabel' => 'Lowest',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'x' => 6162,
    'y' => 62,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'x' => 5948,
    'y' => 73,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'x' => 1,
    'y' => NULL,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'x' => 5936,
    'y' => 36,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'x' => 2731,
    'y' => 9,
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'x' => 454,
    'y' => 7,
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'x' => 5559,
    'y' => 43,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'x' => 2,
    'y' => NULL,
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'x' => 185035,
    'y' => 4641,
    'indexLabel' => 'Highest',
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'x' => 2537,
    'y' => 1,
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'x' => 3075,
    'y' => 13,
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    'x' => 29,
    'y' => NULL,
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    'x' => 128,
    'y' => NULL,
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    'x' => 712,
    'y' => 13,
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'x' => 9,
    'y' => 2,
  ),
)
```

**Full example**

*Note: replaced `echo` calls for HTML in-favor of using textual context, by closing php tags.* Also fixed Markup layout of the HTML; `<table>` does not belong in the `<head>` element.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: *************************************"
    ],
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $array = json_decode($response,true);
    $result = $array['response'];
    $dataPoints = [];
    $phH = $phL = $highest = $lowest = null; 
    ?>
    <table class='styled-chart' id=''>
        <?php foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $dataPoints[$key] = [
                'x' => $cases = $value['cases']['total'],
                'y' => $deaths = $value['deaths']['total'],
            ];
            if (null === $phH || $highest < $deaths) {
                // determine highest point
                $highest = $deaths ? : 0;
                $phH = $key;
            }
            if (null === $phL || $lowest > $deaths) {
                // determine lowest point
                $lowest = $deaths ? : 0;
                $phL = $key;
            }
            /* draw the table row */
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Countries</th>
                <td><?php echo $value['country'] ?></td>
                <th>Cases</th>
                <td><?php echo $cases ?></td>
                <th>Deaths</th>
                <td><?php echo $deaths ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } /* end of table row */ ?>
    </table>
    <?php if (!empty($dataPoints)) {
        // assign highest and lowest points
        $dataPoints[$phL]['indexLabel'] = 'Lowest';
        $dataPoints[$phH]['indexLabel'] = 'Highest';
    }
}

// ...
```

**Result**

```html
<table class="styled-chart" id=""><tbody><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Antigua-and-Barbuda</td><th>Cases</th><td>7539</td><th>Deaths</th><td>135</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Liberia</td><th>Cases</th><td>7402</td><th>Deaths</th><td>294</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>St-Vincent-Grenadines</td><th>Cases</th><td>6751</td><th>Deaths</th><td>106</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Vanuatu</td><th>Cases</th><td>6332</td><th>Deaths</th><td>7</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Nauru</td><th>Cases</th><td>3</td><th>Deaths</th><td></td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>British-Virgin-Islands</td><th>Cases</th><td>6162</td><th>Deaths</th><td>62</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Sao-Tome-and-Principe</td><th>Cases</th><td>5948</td><th>Deaths</th><td>73</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Micronesia</td><th>Cases</th><td>1</td><th>Deaths</th><td></td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Turks-and-Caicos</td><th>Cases</th><td>5936</td><th>Deaths</th><td>36</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Anguilla</td><th>Cases</th><td>2731</td><th>Deaths</th><td>9</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Wallis-and-Futuna</td><th>Cases</th><td>454</td><th>Deaths</th><td>7</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Saint-Kitts-and-Nevis</td><th>Cases</th><td>5559</td><th>Deaths</th><td>43</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Saint-Helena</td><th>Cases</th><td>2</td><th>Deaths</th><td></td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>China</td><th>Cases</th><td>185035</td><th>Deaths</th><td>4641</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Saint-Pierre-Miquelon</td><th>Cases</th><td>2537</td><th>Deaths</th><td>1</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Kiribati</td><th>Cases</th><td>3075</td><th>Deaths</th><td>13</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Vatican-City</td><th>Cases</th><td>29</td><th>Deaths</th><td></td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Falkland-Islands</td><th>Cases</th><td>128</td><th>Deaths</th><td></td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>Diamond-Princess</td><th>Cases</th><td>712</td><th>Deaths</th><td>13</td></tr><tr><th>Countries</th><td>MS-Zaandam</td><th>Cases</th><td>9</td><th>Deaths</th><td>2</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

---

For a more traditional table with heading columns the following format can be used.

```
<table class='styled-chart' id=''>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Countries</th>
        <th>Cases</th>
        <th>Deaths</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
          // ... 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value['country'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cases ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $deaths ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Result**

```html
<table class="styled-chart" id=""><thead><tr><th>Countries</th><th>Cases</th><th>Deaths</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Antigua-and-Barbuda</td><td>7539</td><td>135</td></tr><tr><td>Liberia</td><td>7402</td><td>294</td></tr><tr><td>St-Vincent-Grenadines</td><td>6751</td><td>106</td></tr><tr><td>Vanuatu</td><td>6332</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>Nauru</td><td>3</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>British-Virgin-Islands</td><td>6162</td><td>62</td></tr><tr><td>Sao-Tome-and-Principe</td><td>5948</td><td>73</td></tr><tr><td>Micronesia</td><td>1</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Turks-and-Caicos</td><td>5936</td><td>36</td></tr><tr><td>Anguilla</td><td>2731</td><td>9</td></tr><tr><td>Wallis-and-Futuna</td><td>454</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>Saint-Kitts-and-Nevis</td><td>5559</td><td>43</td></tr><tr><td>Saint-Helena</td><td>2</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>China</td><td>185035</td><td>4641</td></tr><tr><td>Saint-Pierre-Miquelon</td><td>2537</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Kiribati</td><td>3075</td><td>13</td></tr><tr><td>Vatican-City</td><td>29</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Falkland-Islands</td><td>128</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Diamond-Princess</td><td>712</td><td>13</td></tr><tr><td>MS-Zaandam</td><td>9</td><td>2</td></tr></tbody></table>
```